# How to query record based on timestamp and boolean value?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have a payment table where I am storing payment related data.

```
Student_id   is_payment_done   timestamp

A111A11      false             2016/11/23 00:00:00  
A111A11      false             2016/11/24 12:12:00                  
A111A11      false             2016/11/24 16:20:11*  
B234A12      false           
B234A12      false           
B124A12      true           
B123A12      false
```

Here I have student_id foreign key. Now I want to select the record against student_id where `is_payment_done=false` and I want to display the latest record for eg. in above table `A111A11` record have all `is_payment_dont=false` and latest record is with timestamp as `2016/11/24 16:20:11*`

I am very novice with SQL, I have tried using group by `student_id` but I don't know which aggregate function to use and how to check boolean fields of all the records after grouping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My SQL method, there is no need for the sub query or anything because if all the records are false then the `MAX(timestamp)` is also false.  If you didn't limit all records you could still use conditional aggregation to find the `MAX(false timestamp)`.

```
SELECT
    Student_id
    ,MAX(timestamp) as MaxTimeStamp
FROM
    @Payment
GROUP BY
    Student_id
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = COUNT(CASE WHEN is_payment_done = 'false' THEN 1 END)
```

Note however in your example data A111A11, B123A12, and B234A12 all have only records where `is_payment_done = 'false'`

Comment: Somerecords might have combination of false and true values.

Comment: @piechuckerr yeah it looked to me like you don't want them when they have true and false? My query will get the max timestamp of any student_id that has only false records

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Payment
WHERE Student_id = 'A111A11' AND
  is_payment_done = 'false'
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: This is for 1 student, there are thousands of students. Query shouldn't  be static

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your question.  You will need to use a `GROUP BY` clause then as shown by @vkp.